# Shellcode execution error Segmentation Fault in C

Tags: c, gcc, segmentation-fault, shellcode, objdump

I tried to execute shellcode in c. But I got Segmentation Fault error.
I tried on Kali Linux virtual machine. The purpose of shellcode is to print hello shellcode to the screen
It's mine code:

```
// shellcode_example.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello, Shellcode!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

It's extract of hex code:

```
gcc -o shellcode_example shellcode_example.c
objdump -d -M intel shellcode_example
```

```
080484b6 <main>:
  80484b6:   55                      push   ebp
  80484b7:   89 e5                   mov    ebp,esp
  80484b9:   83 ec 08                sub    esp,0x8
  80484bc:   68 60 86 04 08          push   0x8048660
  80484c1:   e8 aa fe ff ff          call   8048370 <puts@plt>
  80484c6:   83 c4 04                add    esp,0x4
  80484c9:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x0
  80484ce:   c9                      leave
  80484cf:   c3                      ret
```

It's shellcode execution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

// Shellcode: Bu, örnek bir NOP (no-operation) shellcode'dur
unsigned char shellcode[] = {
    0x90, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90, 0xC3 // Think, it's mine shellcode.
};

int main() {
    
    void *mem = mmap(NULL, sizeof(shellcode), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE, -1, 0);

    if (mem == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("mmap");
        return 1;
    }

    // Shellcode'ı tahsis edilen belleğe kopyala
    memcpy(mem, shellcode, sizeof(shellcode));

    // Bir işlev işaretçisi oluştur ve bellek konumuna dönüştür
    typedef void (*ShellcodeFunction)();
    ShellcodeFunction func = (ShellcodeFunction)mem;

    // Shellcode'ı yürüt
    func();

    // Tahsis edilen belleği serbest bırak
    munmap(mem, sizeof(shellcode));

    return 0;
}
```

Is there any solution ?
I tried all solution on Internet.

I tried to:

```
gcc -fno-stack-protector -z execstack -O OutputFileName yourShellCode.c
```

I used local and global variable but no change.

**Update:**

Here is my new shell code:

```
unsigned char shellcode[] = {
 0xb8, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xbb, 0x01, 0x00,
 0x00, 0x00, 0xb9 ,0x00 ,0xa0 ,0x04, 0x08, 0xba,
 0x0d ,0x00 ,0x00, 0x00 ,0xcd ,0x80 ,0xb8, 0x01,
 0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00, 0x31, 0xdb, 0xcd, 0x80
};
```

and asm code of shellcode:

```
section .data
     hello db 'Hello, World!',0
section .text
     global _start  _start:     
      ; write system call
     mov eax, 4
     mov ebx, 1
     mov ecx, hello
     mov edx, 13
     int 0x80
      ; exit system call
     mov eax, 1
     xor ebx, ebx
     int 0x80
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

I "over-indexed" on the "shell code" payload. Your actual target of the injection doesn't use your shell code *at all* -- it simply executes 4 `NOP`s followed by `RET`, and thus doesn't do anything.

**Update 2:**
The new shell code disassembles to:

```
objdump -D xx.o

0000000000000000 <shellcode>:
   0:   b8 04 00 00 00          mov    $0x4,%eax
   5:   bb 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%ebx
   a:   b9 00 a0 04 08          mov    $0x804a000,%ecx
   f:   ba 0d 00 00 00          mov    $0xd,%edx
  14:   cd 80                   int    $0x80
  16:   b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
  1b:   31 db                   xor    %ebx,%ebx
  1d:   cd 80                   int    $0x80
```

Note the `0x804a000` address. This shell code is position dependent and will *not* run correctly unless `mmap` returns exactly the `0x804a000` address.

You need to make this code position-*independent* (by using `PC`-relative addressing or pushing the `Hello ...` string on the stack and passing the stack address to the `write` system call).

---

> `objdump -d -M intel shellcode_example`

The `objdump` shows two things which are wrong:

1. You've built a position-*dependent* binary
2. You've built it to call into dynamically-linked `libc` (`puts` here).

A position-dependent binary *must* be loaded at the address it was linked at (`0x08048000` here). You can't `mmap` that binary at arbitrary address and expect it to work).

And a dynamically linked binary *requires* that the runtime loader sets up that binary's program linkage table (so calls to `puts@plt` get resolved to the symbol definition inside `libc.so`). But the runtime loader is completely unaware of this binary's existence, and so doesn't do *anything* for that binary.

TL;DR: "shell code" must avoid using absolute addresses and dynamic linking (which is why it usually is written in assembly).

Comment: So, What should i do ? How can i fix my code ? Please explain.

Comment: @FidelioRainbow I _have_ explained. Rewrite your "shell code" in assembly (or find a working example).

Comment: I tried to rewrite assembly code. Now, i'm not getting any error but i can't see anything on the screen. But my assembly code write Hello world when i execute my asm code

Comment: @FidelioRainbow I've updated the answer -- _of course_ you don't see any output -- you don't use your "shell code" in the first place.

Comment: It's my new shellcode: `unsigned char shellcode[] = {0xb8,0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xbb, 0x01 ,0x00 ,0x00, 0x00, 0xb9 ,0x00 ,0xa0 ,0x04, 0x08, 0xba, 0x0d ,0x00 ,0x00, 0x00 ,0xcd ,0x80 ,0xb8 ,0x01, 0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00, 0x31, 0xdb, 0xcd, 0x80};
` and asm code of shellcode : `section .data
    hello db 'Hello, World!',0

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    ; write system call
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, hello
    mov edx, 13
    int 0x80

    ; exit system call
    mov eax, 1
    xor ebx, ebx
    int 0x80`

Comment: @FidelioRainbow 1. Don't put code into comments, edit your question instead. 2. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I understand. I tried to get shellcode from compiled c file. So, I didn't write asm code. Now, I know, we need to position independent shellcode for execute.

Comment: Also, I tried to execute independent shellcode. I got no error but i didn't see any result.